# Casting System.Type to a specific class

Tags: c#, oop, reflection, casting

I'm getting the desired System.Type using reflection. I need to check if it is a descendant of Component class. If it is I need to add this particular class to List. What is the proper way to convert types?

```
  foreach (Type curType in allTypes)
  {
     if (curType descends from Component)
       componentsList.Add( (Component)curType );
  }
```

Comment: You can not cast  curType to Component. You need to create an instance of it. Activator.CreateInstance is your friend.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what the problem is you want solved. You cannot cast a type, as stated, and why do you want to add a `class` to a list? Or do you have a specific instance you want in the list?

Comment: I need to create a list of all types that implement a certain interface, and are also descendants of Component. This list will be later used for finding instances of that particular type.

Comment: Then why don't you just add the type to the list?

Comment: @Stephen I get a error - Argument type 'System.Type' isn't assignable to parameter type 'Component'.

Comment: @IlyaSuzdalnitski : then make your componentslist of type `List<Type>`, you have done the check if they inherit from `Component` already, so only those types will end up in that list.

Comment: @IlyaSuzdalnitski and as you state in your comment: `I need to create a list of all types`, so, make a list of type Type ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting of a type is not possible, but as you say in the comments:

> I need to create a list of all types

So make your componentslist of type `List<Type>`, and add the types to that list.

You have done the check if they inherit from Component already, so only those types will end up in that list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`IsSubClassOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (typeof(Component).Equals(curType) || curType.IsSubClassOf(typeof(Component)))
{ }
```

Nonetheless, the `Type` is still a *type*, and not an *instance*, so if you think of adding instances to the list, you should check the instance, not the type.

If you have an instance, you'd better use `is`:

```
if (instance is Component)
{ }
```

If you intend to create a new instance of a specific type, use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(curType);
```

Comment: `IsAssignableFrom` is doing a different job. It checks the assignment compatibility not if the type is descendant of the given type. This will report true for `IEnumerable<T>` due to covariance, but not actually derived.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [IsSubClassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Note: this will report false if the `curType` is of same type of `Component`. You may need to add `Equals` check in that case.

```
if (curType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Component)))
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: And that's why he's better of using `IsAssignableFrom`, as stated in Patrick Hofmans answer, if that is indeed the problem he's trying to solve

Comment: @Stephen Refer my comment below patrick's answer. It is completely doing a different job and can cause trouble if you don't know what it is doing.

Comment: I just read that, and yes, you're right. Overlooked that part (that's what you get for commenting while digesting lunch)